# Free falling into a black hole: time to the singularity doubt!

Tags: black-holes, spacetime, time, singularities, free-fall

I have trying to get a more precise insight into the calculation of the time to the singularity of a test mass into a non-rotatic uncharged black hole.

Prelude: the lagrangian for a massive particle in GR reads
\begin{equation}
L=-m\sqrt{-g_{\mu\nu} \dot{x}^\mu\dot{ x}^\nu}
\end{equation}
Energy is
\begin{equation}
-E=\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{t}}=-\dfrac{m^2 g_{tt} \dot{t}}{L}=constant
\end{equation}
We also have
\begin{equation}
g_{tt}\dot{t}^2+g_{rr}\dot{r}^2=-1
\end{equation}
From this equation we get
\begin{equation}
\dot{r}^2=-\left(1-\dfrac{2GM}{r}\right)+\dfrac{E}{m}
\end{equation}
Above, I used natural units with $c=1$ for simplicity. Taking $E=m$, leaves you with
\begin{equation}
\dot{r}^2=\dfrac{2GM}{r}
\end{equation}
that is indeed the classical escape velocity from a massive $M$ body for a test $m$ particle. Also, the dot means, I believe, differentiation with respect to proper or affine parameter $\tau=\lambda$.
However, I have seen two different procedures:

1st method. For a test mass $m$, the free fall time to the singularity can be estimated from the integral

\begin{equation}
t=\int \dfrac{dr}{\sqrt{-g_{rr}}}
\end{equation}
That is, I integrate the negative of the radial ``gravitational potential'' (the metric field).
\begin{equation}
    t_s=\frac{1}{c}\int_0^{R_S}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\dfrac{2GM}{c^2r}-1}}~dr=\frac{\pi GM}{c^3}=\dfrac{\pi R_S}{2c}\simeq \frac{M}{M_\odot}\times 1.54\times 10^{-5}~{\rm s}.
\end{equation}
So, in summary,
\begin{equation}
t_S = \dfrac{\pi GM}{c^3}
\end{equation}

2nd method. In this method, we essentially integrate along a geodesic for the particle with mass m. For a particle mass with $E=m$, the free fall time to the singularity can be estimated from
\begin{equation}
   \dfrac{dr}{d\tau}=-\sqrt{\dfrac{2GM}{r}}
\end{equation}
So, making a trip towards the singularity from the radial coordinate $r_0$ at $\tau=0$, carries a time
\begin{equation}
    \int_{r_0}^{r}r^{1/2}dr=-\sqrt{2GM}\int_0^\tau d\tau
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \tau_S=\dfrac{2}{3cR_S^{1/2}}\left(r_0^{3/2}-r^{3/2}\right)
\end{equation}
Taking $r_0=R_S$ and $r=0$, you will obtain
\begin{equation}
\tau_S = \dfrac{2}{3c}R_S= \dfrac{4 GM}{3c^3}=\dfrac{4}{3\pi}t_S
\end{equation}

I believe the second method is right, I think, but I saw the other method and I can not get its meaning, since I believe is "different" from the another one even when they are of the same order of magnitude.

Question: What is the meaning of these and how could this falling time methods be properly  generalized to other black holes like Kerr black holes or SdS or RN?

Comment: Can you explain how you get the formula $\frac{dr}{d\tau} = - \sqrt{\frac{2 GM}{r}}$? Also, I find it a bit unclear when you have defined $t_S = \frac{\pi G M}{c^3}$ and later on you say that $\frac{4 GM}{c^3} = \frac{3 \pi}{4} t_S$. Would you mind clarifying this too? I can just see formulas in your question but I don't see the reasoning behind why either of the expressions should be the time to fall into the singularity. I can see how I can derive the first expression, but I still think it's worth elaborating to make it easier for the person answering to know what confuses you exactly.

Comment: @Stratiev I added some of my detailed calculations. I am doing some notes about Schwarzschild and Kerr black holes (well, black holes in general), and I wanted to include this falling into the singularity stuff when I suddenly realized I did not understand completely how to calculate properly the falling time...

Comment: @Stratiev Well, and about the times...I just wanted to highlight that the two procedures give indeed same order of magnitude times, but I think they can not be both correct. Or can they with different meaning?

Comment: Some formule have been corrected